# Insufficient number of arguments for sp_rename in synapse stored procedure

Tags: sql, azure, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I have this stored procedure in **Synapse dedicated sql pool** that is renaming a staging table to a main table.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RenameStagingTableToDedicatedTable]
(

    @DedicatedTableName VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Check if the Dedicated table exists
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'U' AND name = @DedicatedTableName)
    BEGIN
        -- Rename the staging table to the Dedicated table
        EXEC sp_rename 'gold.Service_Staging', 'gold.Service'
 
        -- Drop the existing Dedicated table
        EXEC ('DROP TABLE ' + @DedicatedTableName)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- The Dedicated table does not exist, so rename the staging table to the Dedicated table
        EXEC sp_rename 'gold.Service_Staging', 'gold.Service'
 
    END
END
GO
```

When executing this stored procedure, I get the following error:

> An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function sp_rename

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`sp_rename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is in preview in  Azure Synapse Analytics:

> **Applies to: Azure Synapse Analytics**
>
> In sp_rename (preview) for Azure Synapse Analytics, COLUMN is a
> mandatory value specifying that the object type to be renamed is a
> column, and must always be included in the sp_rename statement. A
> column can only be renamed if it's not a distribution column.

So it appears you can only rename columns at present (which seems a strange restriction).

Also, it seems that you might have an XY problem. Staging tables are usually created once and truncated, or simply created and dropped as required.

Comment: @Mitch_Wheat Yes I think the SP I'm using is a bit of a mess, I'm trying to figure out the best way to just load my staging table and update my target table without disrupting the end users